# Can I re-heat Ricottta that hasn't seperated into whey fully yet?

Tags: cheese, milk

I am making Ricotta Cheese with Lemon Juice for my acid. I got it to 200 degrees then added my salt and acid. Perhaps i didnt add enough. I have 7 cups milk, 1 cup heavy creme, 3 tsp salt, 5tbsp lemon juice. its been sitting while I make dough. It hasnt completely turned over. I have some small curds. But I do not see whey. Can I reheat this and fix it with more lemon juice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to, if it's still liquid.  The worst that will happen is that you'll end up with a more dry, farmers-cheese curd, but that will still be fine in ravioli.

Incidentally, this is why a lot of folks use granulated citric acid instead of lemon juice.  Juice acidity can vary quite a bit.  Otherwise your quantities look correct.